# My Left Join Query in mySql gives duplicate results even after using DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, inner-join

I have tried many solutions to get rid of Duplicate results in Query but no use. 
Here are my tables:

sparepartorderdetails d table:

```
id ----- SparePartID --------OrderID -------- Qty ----- Price
101-----------47----------------84-------------2--------1500
102-----------49----------------86-------------3--------3000
103-----------52----------------86-------------5--------800
104-----------45----------------87-------------3--------450
105-----------48----------------87-------------2--------1200
```

and sparepartfeedback fb table:

```
PFID -----Review-----------Rating------- SparePartID -----OrderID 
1---------good job------------5--------------49--------------86
2---------nice product--------4--------------52--------------86
```

Now here is my **QUERY**  which gives duplicate results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.SparePartID, s.Name, d.Quantity, d.Price, d.OrderID , 
       fb.PFID, fb.Review, fb.Rating
FROM sparepartorderdetails d LEFT JOIN
     sparepartfeedback fb
     ON fb.OrderID = d.OrderID INNER JOIN
     sparepart s
     ON d.SparePartID= s.SparePartID INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
WHERE d.OrderID = "86"
```

Now these are the duplicate results Im getting:

```
SparePartID-----Name------Qty----Price----OrderID ----PFID ------Review---- Rating**
49 ----------- Lights ---- 3---- 3000 ------86--------1----------good job ------ 5
52 ----------- Mirrors---- 5----- 800-------86--------2----------nice product ------ 5
49 ----------- Lights ---- 3---- 3000 ------86--------1----------good job ------ 5
52 ----------- Mirrors---- 5----- 800-------86--------2----------nice product ------ 5
```

But this Query gives **no duplicates** if there are no reviews/ratings for an order like for **OrderID: 87** it just correctly shows order details and NULL values for Review and Ratings. But when I run it for OrderID: 86 which has Reviews/Ratings, it gives duplicate results.

Below are results that I expect:

```
SparePartID-----Name------Qty----Price----OrderID ----PFID ------Review------- Rating**
49 ----------- Lights ---- 3---- 3000 ------86--------1----------good job ------- 5
52 ----------- Mirrors---- 5----- 800-------86--------2----------nice product --- 5
```

Comment: I don't see "duplicate" results.  Each row is quite different.  I think you have asked the wrong question.  You should explain what you want to do, the data you have, and the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff See my results table where Lights and Mirrors data is shown twice, it is duplicate

Comment: I am not in front of the pc, so I cannot try tour code. Try to use patenthesis in Distinct(SparePartID), etc etc

Comment: "duplicates" is not clear. Also you only say you're getting unwanted ones, you don't say what you acutally want. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have left out a `JOIN` condition on the spare part id:

```
SELECT d.SparePartID, s.Name, d.Quantity, d.Price, d.OrderID , 
       fb.PFID, fb.Review, fb.Rating
FROM sparepartorderdetails d LEFT JOIN
     sparepartfeedback fb
     ON fb.OrderID = d.OrderID
        fp.SparePartID = d.SparePartID INNER JOIN
     sparepart s
     ON d.SparePartID= s.SparePartID INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
WHERE d.OrderID = 86
```